# How to make a function (which calls subscribe method) wait from returning value before data is resolved within subscribe method?

Tags: angular, async-await, subscribe

I am fairly new to Angular and appreciate some guidance here. My **userLoggedIn** function inside the AuthService always returns **false** because this function returns the value of variable **userIsLoggedIn** which is initially assigned **false** and it never reaches the block of code - `this.userIsLoggedIn=res.tokenValid;` inside the callback function passed to subscribe method before executing the return statement. I believe it's due to the asynchronicity nature of javascript handling functions, but how do I prevent execution from reaching to **return statement** before fully executing my callback function so that my function can return **true** if the **validToken** property of my response object contains **true** value?

I tried the followings but didn't help:

1. used async-await on my callback function -

   ````
   this.httpReq.verifyToken(token)
       .subscribe(**async** res =>{
       this.userIsLoggedIn= **await** res.tokenValid;
       })```
   ````
2. made the whole userLoggedIn function *async-await*

   ```
   **async** userLoggedIn():boolean{
        **await** this.httpReq.verifyToken(token)
    }
   ```

```
//Auth Service
export class AuthService {
    userIsLoggedIn=false;
    constructor(private router:Router, private repo:ProductRepository, 
        private httpReq:HttpRequestService) {}

    userLoggedIn():boolean{
        const token=this.getLocalToken();

        if(!token){
            return false;
        }

        this.httpReq.verifyToken(token)
            .subscribe(async res =>{
            this.userIsLoggedIn=await res.tokenValid;
            })

        return this.userIsLoggedIn;

    }
}


//verifyToken method in my HttpRequestService
export class HttpRequestService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    verifyToken(token:string){
        const headers=new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type':'application/json',
          'Authorization':token
        })

        return this.http.post<{message:string, tokenValid:boolean}>('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', null, {headers:headers})

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `userLoggedIn()` function is performing an HTTP call, this function should happen asynchronous (finishing after some time).

**Hint:** To understand better `sync vs async` please have a look over callbacks, async/await, promises, observables.

**Answer:**

```
 userLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean>{
        // Make sure this is sync or need to be chained with the observable below
        const token = this.getLocalToken();

        if(!token){
            return of(false);
        } else {
            return this.httpReq.verifyToken(token).pipe(
                 // Use the tap operator to update some inner class variable
                 tap((res) => this.userIsLoggedIn = res.tokenValid)
                 // We do have the response, if there is ok you can return true. You can add additional validations.
                 switchMap((res) => res ? of(true) : of(false)),
                 // Catch errors, do something with them
                 catchError((err) => of(false))
            )
        }
    }
```

**Small glossary:**

**of** : creates a new observable the provided parameter
**tap**: doesn't affect the stream, can perform operations without side-efects with the response
**switchMap**: similar to `.then(() => new Promise()`

... and finally call the function like:

```
   userLoggedIn().subscribe(isLoggedIn => console.log(isLoggedIn);
```

Comment: `switchMap((res) => res ? of(true) : of(false))` could just be `map(res => res.tokenValid)` or even `pluck('tokenValid')`.

Comment: @fridoo Yes, we can use `pluck` or `map` but I preferred `switchMap` for verbosity and similarity with Promises.

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu Thanks for the solution and explaining some rxjs operators. I was testing your solution by calling **userLoggedIn** function from my authguard just like you suggested but it still returned me 'false' even if res.tokenValid is true;

Comment: @AndrewRadulescu Here's my authguard service

Comment: ```export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    userLoggedIn=false;
    constructor(private auth:AuthService){}
    canActivate(
      route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        this.auth.userLoggedIn().subscribe(isLoggedIn=>this.userLoggedIn=isLoggedIn);
          if(this.userLoggedIn){
            return true;
          }else{
            // some code//
          }
        }
    }```

Comment: @Jaysan You misunderstand how Observables work. Subscribing to an Observable won't pause the execution of your code at that point. A call to `subscribe` returns immediately and any code afterwards is executed straight away, just the code within the subscribe callback is only executed when your Observable emits a value. In general only subscribe at the very last moment where you acutally need do display some data, otherwise keep on returning Observables. On the way use `tap` to peek into the stream and perform some side effect and use `map` to modify the values in the stream.

Comment: @Jaysan First of all please visit some documentation about Javascript in general, asynchronous operations and how the engine is interpreting the code, you will like it.
I will write the solution here but believe me, your learning path is not working this way.
You should just write `return this.auth.userLoggedIn();` inside the `canActivate` function and will work because is returning an Observable<boolean> in the way we defined it and Angular expects. Good luck and keep up!

Comment: I agree. I think I haven't understood the observable quite well. Thanks Fridoo and Andrew for some insights.

Comment: Can you tell us if the solution worked? If so, please approve the answer to help others too.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, it didn't work for me so I ended up using 'fetch' to do http request which returns Promise instead of HttpClient module which returns observable. I was able to achieve what I was expecting with Promise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need use async or await.  The HttpRequestService.verifyToken returns an Observable of type {message:string, tokenValid:boolean}.  You could have the userLoggedIn function also return this Observable then do subscription to userLoggedIn.  You need to get comfortable with RX Observables, but you could have HttpRequestService.verifyToken return a Promise.  In this case that is not a bad idea.